# High order partial derivates in a composition function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Let $ $ $ w (x,y) = f (y-x, x+y) $  , where $  f: \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R $ is a 
 $ \mathcal C^2 $ classe function. Show that $$
4\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u \partial v}  = \frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial y^2} - \frac{\partial ^2 w}{\partial x^2 } $$ knowing that $ u=y-x $  and  $ v=x+y . $

This is how far i could go:

$$ \frac{\partial  w}{\partial x}  = -\frac{\partial  f}{\partial u} + \frac{\partial  f}{\partial v} $$

$$\frac{\partial  w}{\partial y}= \frac{\partial  f}{\partial u} + \frac{\partial  f}{\partial v} $$

Comment: What is stopping you from continuing?

Comment: I don't know how to calculate the 2nd order partial derivatives

Comment: If you could find ${\partial w}{\partial x}$, then why can't you just do it again?

Comment: Because I applied the chain rule to find that, but that rule doesn't seem to work in order to calculate the second order partial derivatives for $w$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $$\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}=-\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial v},$$ then we find via the same process as you employed before that $$\frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial x^2}=\frac{\partial ^2f}{\partial u^2}-2\frac{\partial ^2f}{\partial u\partial v}+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial^2 v}.$$ Similarly, $$\frac{\partial ^2w}{\partial y^2}=\frac{\partial ^2f}{\partial u^2}+2\frac{\partial ^2f}{\partial u\partial v}+\frac{\partial ^2f}{\partial v^2}.$$ Now, just subtract the first from the second. Note that, as you did, I'm omitting the writing the arguments of the functions, but these are important when applying the chain rule.

In general, if $u(x(\xi,\eta),y(\xi,\eta))=U(\xi,\eta),$ then $$u_{xx}=U_{\xi\xi}(\xi_x)^2+2U_{\xi\eta}\xi_x\eta_x+U_{\eta\eta}(\eta_x)^2+U_\xi\xi_{xx}+U_\eta \eta_{xx}.$$

Comment: I don't understand how is that the same process, I applied the chain rule before, I've never seen that formula you wrote at the bottom of your anwser.

Comment: When we take the derivative of $\partial_x w,$ we need to apply the chain rule all over again, to both $\partial_u f$ and $\partial_v f.$ If you understand the chain rule well enough, you should be able to derive the formula that I wrote at the bottom without too much issue.

Comment: Thanks. Worked perfectly the way you told me to do!

Comment: @PTSONIC Great, I'm glad that it helped!